# two files which are not common and get the output

Tags: shell, awk

Objective of this problem is 1.csv has records which are having correct mapping, 2.csv has files with wrong mapping

i want to find the mismatch of rows and coloumns between 1.csv and 2.csv

1.csv

```
1111111111111111:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
3333333333333333:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

2.csv

```
1111111111111111:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1111111111111110:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1111111111111123:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11111111111111:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2622222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyret
2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
4444444444444444:ppppppppppppppp
```

output should be like:

```
2622222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyret
4444444444444444:ppppppppppppppp
```

I have used awk command but not be able to get the desired output

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]++; next} !a[$1]' 1.csv 2.csv
```

consier 1.csv as correct mapping, i want to find the mismatch between 1.csv and 2.csv
for eg 1.csv has this entry

### 2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

which is correct mapping

2.csv has two entries with the same first coloumn but different second coloumn

### 2622222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyret

so the output file should have this wrong mismatch record which is

2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyret

the remaining two lines of output is as below, as these two records are not present in 1.csv but there in 2.csv, hence these are wrong records and should be printed in the output

### 2622222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 4444444444444444:ppppppppppppppp

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense. What's with `3333333333333333:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz` for example?

Comment: for eg 1.csv is the file which has correct mapping, i wanted to find the mismatch of 1.csv and 2.csv in the output

Comment: [edit] your question to show what is the underlying logic in this. Do not expect us to decipher it

Comment: i have edited it and given the expectation, please have a look

Comment: Please explain concisely at the start of your question what you are trying to achieve rather than dumping a bunch of files and saying something is wrong.

Comment: please have alook now

Comment: "2.csv has two entries with the same first coloumn" The second character is different... I give up

Comment: If I get understood the main idea (get records in 2.csv which are not in 1.csv): `grep -v -f 1.csv 2.csv` and read the man page to understand it.

Comment: correct 2.csv has two entries with the same first coloumn but the second cooumn is different, the one which is not present in 1.csv should come as a output  here.

Comment: your desired ouptut is not compliant to what you explain (where are all 1111 wrong lines where there is a similar pattern in 1.csv, 444 where there is no similar pattern in 1.csv...) is there other constraint

Comment: What do you mean by _coloumn_ - the character position column, or one of the two columns separated by `:`?